# Solving linear least squares equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I have great difficulty solving this equation (in the picture, as I don't know how to properly format this using mathJax). 
Since the last time I've seen matrices was about three years ago, I don't have any idea how to tackle this problem. I need to later implement solving it in python, but I guess I first need any idea about what I am about to do.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ja9Cv.jpg

Comment: multiplying all phi-matrices and solving using numpy.linalg.solve(multipliedPhis,y), without result. So i suppose road to solving the problem is different than just multiplying everything mindlessly.

Comment: Yes, you only need to multiply them. THere should be another problem in your code. Perhaps paste it in here?

Comment: `def least_squares(x_train, y_train, M):
    desm=design_matrix(x_train,M)
    desmT=desm.T
    multipliedDesm=np.matmul(desmT,desm)
    multipliedDesm=np.linalg.inv(multipliedDesm)
    partone=np.matmul(multipliedDesm,desmT)
    w=np.matmul(partone,y_train)
    return w`  

for some reason, i cant get linebreaks to function correctly :( But what you are saying is that i just need to multiply all of these with correct order of operations, and there is no need to use linalg.solve?

Comment: You have to differentiate $V(w)=(y-\Phi w)^{'}\cdot (y-\Phi w)=(y^{'}-w^{'}\Phi^{'})\cdot (y-\Phi w)$ w.r.t $w$. But first multiply out the brackets.

Comment: Simple multiplication was enough. I guess that sitting at math for 10 hours straight makes you forget easy ways out. It took me two hours to just look at this literally as it is, and multiply everything. Thanks everyone! :)